# MATLAB : How to assign a default input if it is empty?

Tags: matlab, input, arguments

I have an .m file that starts like this:

```
function [] = foo(n);
```

if the user calls it like `foo(5)` in the command window, it's ok.
But I want the function also run when the user just calls it like `foo` , without the input n.
I handle this in c++ using the array `argv[]`, is there any way to do this in MATLAB?

thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/nargin.html) and related.